# select * query returning data from db

Tags: javascript, sql, node.js, db2, nodemailer

I have a table set up (in my db) where a user can select which category they want to send an email to (from front end). my table set up is like this:

```
name
category1
category2
category3
```

those are all columns. So in each of those category columns are emails. I basically want to grab the data from whichever category the user selects. However, I cannot seem to grab that data.

here's my code to query the db:

```
app.get('/sendBatchCategory', (req, res) => {
var category = req.query.category
category = category.toUpperCase();
var subject = req.query.subject;
var message = req.query.message;

var categoryQuery = ""
if (category == "CATEGORY1") {
    categoryQuery = "SELECT CATEGORY1 FROM EMAILS"
} else if (category == "CATEGORY2") {
    categoryQuery = "SELECT CATEGORY2 FROM EMAILS"
} else if (category == "CATEGORY3") {
    categoryQuery = "SELECT CATEGORY3 FROM EMAILS"
} else if (category == "ALL") {
    categoryQuery = "SELECT CATEGORY1, CATEGORY2, CATEGORY3 FROM EMAILS"
} else {
    alert("category not found, please select a valid category")
}
//"SELECT '" + category + "' FROM EMAILS"
var sendBatchCategory = categoryQuery
ibmdb.open(ibmdbconnDash, function (err, conn) {
    if (err) return console.log(err);
    conn.query(sendBatchCategory, function (err, rows) {
      if (err) {
        console.log(err);
      }

      console.log(rows)
      var listOfEmails = (rows) // here is where I am trying to store the data being called          into a variable to pass into the code to send an email.

      conn.close(function () {
        console.log("closing function sendBatchCategory");
      });
```

code to send an email (all within same function)

```
     // async..await is not allowed in global scope, must use a wrapper
      async function main() {
        // Generate test SMTP service account from ethereal.email
        // Only needed if you don't have a real mail account for testing
        let testAccount = await nodemailer.createTestAccount();
    
        // create reusable transporter object using the default SMTP transport
        let transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
          host: "smtp.gmail.com",
          port: 587,
          secure: false, // true for 465, false for other ports
          auth: {
            user: "x",
            pass: "y",
          },
        });
    // send mail with defined transport object
    let info = await transporter.sendMail({
      from: "x", // sender address
      to: listOfEmails, // list of receivers
      subject: subject, // Subject line
      text: message //message line
    });

    sendBatchSuccess(req, res)

    console.log("Message sent: %s", info.messageId);
    // Message sent: <b658f8ca-6296-ccf4-8306-87d57a0b4321@example.com>

    // Preview only available when sending through an Ethereal account
    console.log("Preview URL: %s", nodemailer.getTestMessageUrl(info));
    // Preview URL: https://ethereal.email/message/WaQKMgKddxQDoou...
  }

  main().catch(console.error);
 
        });
    });
})
```

the result that I get from the rows is

```
{ CATEGORY1: email1 }
{ CATEGORY1: email2 }
{ CATEGORY1: email3 }
```

but when it runs the email code, I get the error:

```
Error: No recipients defined
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to extract the email list

```js
ibmdb.open(ibmdbconnDash, function (err, conn) {
    if (err) return console.log(err);
    conn.query(sendBatchCategory, function (err, rows) {
      if (err) {
        console.log(err);
      }

      console.log(rows);
      var listOfEmails =[];
      rows.foreach(function(entry){
         if(entry.hasOwnProperty('CATEGORY1')){
              listOfEmails.push(entry.CATEGORY1);
         }
        if(entry.hasOwnProperty('CATEGORY2')){
              listOfEmails.push(entry.CATEGORY2);
         }
         if(entry.hasOwnProperty('CATEGORY3')){
              listOfEmails.push(entry.CATEGORY3);
         }
      })
      conn.close(function () {
        console.log("closing function sendBatchCategory");
      });
```

// send mail with defined transport object

```
    let info = await transporter.sendMail({
      from: "x", // sender address
      to: listOfEmails.join(","), // list of receivers
      subject: subject, // Subject line
      text: message //message line
    });
```

Comment: I did try what you said above, and received the error `rows.foreach is not a function`. not sure how to fix

Comment: you try to change "foreach"  to ''forEach"